# Perl CPAN-style Packaging with no lib/*.pm

Tags: perl, package, cpan

I've got a collection of Perl scripts and a couple XML data files that they depend on which I'd like to distribute. Currently, I've got a shell script which copies bin/* and share/* to a target installation tree. It seems a little clunky, so I'd like to go with something like the standard CPAN way of packaging Perl.

Does is make sense to bundle what I've got in a CPAN-style package? I suspect there is nothing wrong with it, but every tutorial I've looked at thinks that lib/Blah.pm is an essential file in any package - I don't even have a lib/ directory, let alone any .pm files.

Is there a standard solution for packaging a collection of Perl scripts, along with some data in a share/ directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Distributions don't care about modules. Most of the tools are set up to handle modules by default because that's the common case, but you can really distribute anything as long as you provide the logic to tell the build files what to do with whatever files that you provide.

ExtUtils::Makemaker is difficult to use for this sort of thing, but Module::Build (despite the word "Module") makes it much easier. However, you have to know a bit about custom Module::Build classes so you can override the default behavior that you don't want.

If you are talking about standalone scripts, you can look at my [scriptdist](http://search.cpan.org/dist/scriptdist) distribution, or the [Dr. Dobbs article I wrote about it](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/184416112). It won't handle the *share/* portion for you, but it's not too hard to add.

Comment: If the build system really is grumpy, you can always create a lib/App/MyApp.pm file just to contain $VERSION or what-have-you. It might be a good idea if you're publishing on CPAN anyway, to make searching for it easier.

Comment: This probably isn't the place for it, but the `make test` fails on `script dist`. Is there somewhere set up to discuss such problems?

Comment: Module::Build 0.36 has the [share_dir](http://p3rl.org/Module::Build::API#share_dir) option, no need to write any extra code.

Comment: Is it wise to use Module::Build 0.36? I use Ubuntu and the package manager is still quite a number of versions behind it. Considering I'm doing this for distribution, should I not stick to what I can safely assume everyone has?

Comment: If you want to use scriptdist, you have to fix it yourself. I don't recommend using it. Just look at what it's supposed to do. :) But, as with all CPAN distributions, you report problems on http://rt.cpan.org.