# How do I use a CPAN module in a perl script that I want to give to others?

Tags: excel, perl, module, cpan

I'm writing a Perl script that takes data and writes it to an Excel file. I'm using [`Excel::Writer::XLSX`](http://metacpan.org/module/Excel::Writer::XLSX) to do this.

I'm hoping to write the script and then give it to the rest of my team so we can all use it to compile the data when we need to.

I have a few questions about this:

1. Do my colleagues need to have the module installed to for the script to work?
2. If not, how do I wrap up the module with the script to give it to them?
3. Is there a better way of doing this that using the module I've chosen?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4741142/2766176

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways of doing this. One options is to put together a `Makefile.PL` that specifies the dependencies. This allows you to bundle your script as a distribution. E.g.

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile(
    ABSTRACT          => 'myscript creates Excel files',
    AUTHOR            => 'A.U. Thor',
    EXE_FILES         => [ 'myscript' ],
    NAME              => 'myscript',
    VERSION           => '1.2.3',

    PREREQ_PM => {
        'Excel::Writer::XLSX' => '0.88',
    },
);
```

Then, people can do `perl Makefile.PL` which will inform them of the dependencies. If you do `make dist`, and distribute the resulting archive file, they can also use [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) to install your script along with its dependencies.

Another option is to put together a [cpanfile](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Module-CPANfile/lib/cpanfile.pod). Then, recipients can install all the dependencies using a tool such as [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus).

Now, if you are distributing the script to people who do not use Perl normally, and you want them to be able to just click and run etc, you might want to look into [pp](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp).

Comment: I don't think either you or Brian have addressed the OP's specific questions

Answer (score 3):

A long time ago, I wrote a program I called scriptdist to turn a single-file program into a CPAN-like distribution, complete with a build file. That way you could pass it around as an archive and people could treat it like any other CPAN distribution. It basically automates [what Sinan posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35509772/2766176). I wrote about it for [Dr. Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/automating-distributions-with-scriptdist/184416112).

There's a trick that you can use if you want to pass around the archive. The `cpan` tool can install from the current directory. That will get the dependencies (which, by the nature of being dependencies, are required):

```
 $ cpan .
```

That way, you can install your program and its dependencies without putting anything in a CPAN-like repository.

Comment: I don't think either you or Sinan have addressed the OP's specific questions

Comment: I disagree. I don't think that your answer improves what Sinan and I have said, and you bring in more issues than necessary to give his co-workers his program.

Comment: You may be right, and perhaps I have misunderstood the original question. But in this case, especially as you are ignoring the OP's three itemised questions, I think it would help a lot to describe precisely what problem you are answering

Answer (score -4):

It's far from clear what you need to know

> Do my colleagues need to have the module installed to for the script to work?

I think it's obvious that your colleagues need access to your code to be able to make use of it

It's not clear what you have written, but if you have created a module then any program with access to your module files can simply `use` it to access its capabilities

> If not, how do I wrap up the module with the script to give it to them?

Your *"if not"* isn't clear. What you have written means *"If they don't need to have the module installed to for the script to work"*, and I doubt if that is your intention

*"how do I wrap up the module with the script"* Are you asking how to create a module, or do you already have one? Typically, modules are accessed by programmers who write a script with the `use` statement

If you have a module and you want other people to be able to load it with `use` then it must appear in one of the directories listed in their `@INC` array. If you are working on separate systems then it is best to create a package that you can alter as necessary and have others update

> Is there a better way of doing this (than) using the module I've chosen?

Are you referring to `Excel::Writer::XLSX` or your own module?

If `Excel::Writer::XLSX` is doing what you need then you probably shgouldn't change. But if you are having problems with it in some way then you need to ask a new question and describe those issues